Scale canvas/matrix and all transformations applied, to obtain better quality image in the canvas
A member from stackoferflow helped fix my script and he obtained a good result, but I still need some help.
I have a DIV that contains some other divs and in the end, an image.
This image is bigger in size, but has a smaller width/height set directly from CSS (3x times smaller, the number is irrelevant).
The image has CSS transformations applied to it (rotate/scale, translate).

The script creates a canvas, of the same size as the div, and draws the image in the canvas, CROPPING the outside part of it (filling it with white). Finally it draws the image in it's normal position (with no rotation applied to it), but with the outside part, in white (so cropped).
It works perfect. The problem is that I would like to scale this canvas 3 times (or 5 times) to make it better quality, since my image is bigger (natural size), but it's displayed smaller due to the CSS exact width/height set.
I tried rescaling (resizing) the canvas but it simply produces bad results, as it's rescales a small image (losing a lot of quality).
I would like to modify the script, so it applied scaling on all steps based on a scale factor (let's say SCALE_FACTOR=3).
In my example, the div size is 400x400 pixels, so the final canvas would be 1200x1200 pixels and the image would be drawn 3 times bigger, but in EXACTLY the same position (so the crop result is identical, just in higher quality).
I tried applying .scale on the matrix and inverse matrix, but it does not give the result I am looking for. Of course I increased containerWidth with *SCALE_FACTOR etc...
I would like to obtain this (but high quality draw, not rescale like I did now) .

Here is the code I am using:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 20px;
}

.object-render--canvas {
  width: 400px;
  /* You can change this to any size */
  height: 400px;
  /* You can change this to any size */
  border: 2px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

 #dd6f9f50-780e-11ef-b763-11ebd40cd3a6 {
      width: 326px; /* Scaled-down width */
      height: 290.3px; /* Scaled-down height */
      transform: translate(230px, -130px) rotate(145deg) scale(1);
      transform-origin: center center;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }

#buttons {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#tempCanvases {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}

#tempCanvases canvas {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Dynamic Image Transformation and Cropping</h1>
<div class="object-render--canvas">
  <img id="dd6f9f50-780e-11ef-b763-11ebd40cd3a6" src="https://i.sstatic.net/oJs20ysA.png" alt="Source Image">
</div>
<div id="buttons">
  <button id="processButton">Process</button>
  <button id="downloadButton" disabled>Download</button>
</div>
<h2>Temporary Canvases (For Debugging)</h2>

<script type='text/javascript'>
// Wait for the DOM to load
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const processButton = document.getElementById('processButton');
  const downloadButton = document.getElementById('downloadButton');
  
  let finalCanvas = null;
  let finalImageCanvas=null;

  processButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Clear previous temporary canvases
    downloadButton.disabled = true;

    processCanvas();

    // Enable the download button
    downloadButton.disabled = false;
  });

  downloadButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (!finalCanvas) return;

    // Convert the final canvas to a data URL
    const dataURL = finalCanvas.toDataURL('image/png');

    // Create a temporary link to trigger download
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = dataURL;
    link.download = 'processed_image.png';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  });

  /**
   * Utility function to append a canvas with a label for debugging
   * @param {HTMLCanvasElement} canvas 
   * @param {string} label 
   */
   
  function processCanvas(){

    const sourceImage = document.getElementById('dd6f9f50-780e-11ef-b763-11ebd40cd3a6');
  // Step 1: Get container and image dimensions
    const container = document.getElementsByClassName("object-render--canvas")[0];
    const containerWidth = container.clientWidth;
    const containerHeight = container.clientHeight;

    const imageRenderedWidth = sourceImage.width;
    const imageRenderedHeight = sourceImage.height;
    

    // Step 2: Get computed styles of the image
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(sourceImage);
    const transform = style.transform;

    // Calculate the center of the image
    const centerX = imageRenderedWidth / 2;
    const centerY = imageRenderedHeight / 2;

    // If no transform is applied, set it to identity matrix
    const matrix = transform === 'none' ?
      new DOMMatrix() :
      new DOMMatrix(transform)
    
      // Apply the transform-origin
        .preMultiplySelf({ e: centerX, f: centerY })
        .multiply({ e: -centerX, f: -centerY })
    

    
    //this is the canvas where we revert transformations and crop image
    finalCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    finalCanvas.width = containerWidth;
    finalCanvas.height = containerHeight;
    finalCanvas.style.border="1px solid red";
    const ctx1 = finalCanvas.getContext('2d');


    ctx1.setTransform(matrix);
    // Draw the image transformed
    ctx1.drawImage(sourceImage, 0, 0, imageRenderedWidth, imageRenderedHeight);


    //above code draws the image, identical as in the div, after this line, we reset transformations and crop everything that is outside the canvas with white, and display the image in normal (non rotated, not css scaled) position.
    // Draw again, using the inverse transform
    ctx1.setTransform(matrix.inverse());
    // Replace the previous content by the new content
    ctx1.globalCompositeOperation = "copy";
    ctx1.drawImage(ctx1.canvas, 0, 0);

    // Fill with white below the current drawing
    ctx1.fillStyle = '#FFFFFF';
    ctx1.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over"; // Draw below
    ctx1.resetTransform(); // No transform
    ctx1.fillRect(0, 0, finalCanvas.width, finalCanvas.height);
    
    
    
    

    // Append the canvas for debugging
    appendCanvas(finalCanvas, 'Result');
  }
  function appendCanvas(canvas, label) {
    const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    const caption = document.createElement('p');
    caption.textContent = label;
    wrapper.appendChild(caption);
    wrapper.appendChild(canvas);
    document.body.appendChild(wrapper);
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>




You need to apply the scale factor to both the transform matrix and its inverse:
new DOMMatrix(transform)
  // Apply the transform-origin
  .preMultiplySelf({ e: centerX, f: centerY })
  .multiply({ e: -centerX, f: -centerY })
  // Apply the scale factor
  // We want it to apply even on the CSS transform we just set,
  // so either we use it as the initial DOMMatrix,
  // or we pre-multiply with it last.
  .preMultiplySelf(scaleMatrix);


And then when applying the inverse to draw back untransformed, we reapply it, because inverse() also inverts that scaling.
// Draw again, using the inverse transform
ctx1.setTransform(matrix.inverse().preMultiplySelf(scaleMatrix));



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 20px;
}

.object-render--canvas {
  width: 400px;
  /* You can change this to any size */
  height: 400px;
  /* You can change this to any size */
  border: 2px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

 #dd6f9f50-780e-11ef-b763-11ebd40cd3a6 {
      width: 326px; /* Scaled-down width */
      height: 290.3px; /* Scaled-down height */
      transform: translate(230px, -130px) rotate(145deg) scale(1);
      transform-origin: center center;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }

#buttons {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#tempCanvases {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}

#tempCanvases canvas {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Dynamic Image Transformation and Cropping</h1>
<div class="object-render--canvas">
  <img id="dd6f9f50-780e-11ef-b763-11ebd40cd3a6" src="https://i.sstatic.net/oJs20ysA.png" alt="Source Image">
</div>
<div id="buttons">
  <button id="processButton">Process</button>
  <button id="downloadButton" disabled>Download</button>
</div>
<h2>Temporary Canvases (For Debugging)</h2>

<script type='text/javascript'>
// Wait for the DOM to load
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const processButton = document.getElementById('processButton');
  const downloadButton = document.getElementById('downloadButton');
  
  let finalCanvas = null;
  let finalImageCanvas=null;

  processButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Clear previous temporary canvases
    downloadButton.disabled = true;

    processCanvas();

    // Enable the download button
    downloadButton.disabled = false;
  });

  downloadButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (!finalCanvas) return;

    // Convert the final canvas to a data URL
    const dataURL = finalCanvas.toDataURL('image/png');

    // Create a temporary link to trigger download
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = dataURL;
    link.download = 'processed_image.png';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  });

  /**
   * Utility function to append a canvas with a label for debugging
   * @param {HTMLCanvasElement} canvas 
   * @param {string} label 
   */
   
  function processCanvas(){

    const sourceImage = document.getElementById('dd6f9f50-780e-11ef-b763-11ebd40cd3a6');
  // Step 1: Get container and image dimensions
    const container = document.getElementsByClassName("object-render--canvas")[0];
    const containerWidth = container.clientWidth;
    const containerHeight = container.clientHeight;

    const imageRenderedWidth = sourceImage.width;
    const imageRenderedHeight = sourceImage.height;
    const scale = sourceImage.naturalWidth / imageRenderedWidth;
    const scaleMatrix = DOMMatrix.fromMatrix({ a: scale, d: scale });

    // Step 2: Get computed styles of the image
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(sourceImage);
    const transform = style.transform;

    // Calculate the center of the image
    const centerX = imageRenderedWidth / 2;
    const centerY = imageRenderedHeight / 2;

    // If no transform is applied, set it to identity matrix
    const matrix = transform === 'none' ?
      scaleMatrix :
      new DOMMatrix(transform)
        // Apply the transform-origin
        .preMultiplySelf({ e: centerX, f: centerY })
        .multiply({ e: -centerX, f: -centerY })
        // Apply scale factor
        .preMultiplySelf(scaleMatrix);
    
    //this is the canvas where we revert transformations and crop image
    finalCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    finalCanvas.width = containerWidth * scale;
    finalCanvas.height = containerHeight * scale;
    finalCanvas.style.border="1px solid red";
    const ctx1 = finalCanvas.getContext('2d');


    ctx1.setTransform(matrix);
    // Draw the image transformed
    ctx1.drawImage(sourceImage, 0, 0, imageRenderedWidth, imageRenderedHeight);


    //above code draws the image, identical as in the div, after this line, we reset transformations and crop everything that is outside the canvas with white, and display the image in normal (non rotated, not css scaled) position.
    // Draw again, using the inverse transform
    ctx1.setTransform(matrix.inverse().preMultiplySelf(scaleMatrix));
    // Replace the previous content by the new content
    ctx1.globalCompositeOperation = "copy";
    ctx1.drawImage(ctx1.canvas, 0, 0);

    // Fill with white below the current drawing
    ctx1.fillStyle = '#FFFFFF';
    ctx1.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over"; // Draw below
    ctx1.resetTransform(); // No transform
    ctx1.fillRect(0, 0, finalCanvas.width, finalCanvas.height);

    // Append the canvas for debugging
    appendCanvas(finalCanvas, 'Result');
  }
  function appendCanvas(canvas, label) {
    const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    const caption = document.createElement('p');
    caption.textContent = label;
    wrapper.appendChild(caption);
    wrapper.appendChild(canvas);
    document.body.appendChild(wrapper);
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>




Almost perfect, thank you. The problem is, if let's say we have scale 0.3 (in css) for image #dd6f9f50-780e-11ef-b763-11ebd40cd3a6 . It draws it big (normal size) in the canvas as it is supposed to be, but the quality is bad. Since it's scale drawing, and the image is big, shouldn't it give the same result good quality result? It's like it's resizing instead of drawing scaled. Give it a try, set scale (0.2) and see the end result. I would appreciate your input on this.

Digging a bit, it seems the problem is with the first drawImage ctx1.drawImage(this, 0, 0, imageRenderedWidth, imageRenderedHeight);  . Because it's drawing it small, and then resizing. Here we should draw it scaled, but in the same position. Simply drawing it scaled here does not help, because the position will be off.

Yes, that's expected, the first drawing does rasterize the first transformation. You might be able to keep a bit of it by applying the invert of the final scale to the scaleFactor, but you won't get a perfect 1-1 result anyway, because a simple rotate(111deg) will produce an imprecise scaling and with flaoting point precision there is no way to get the exact inverse of it.

Thank you. So you think there is no solution for this? Because for example, if we have image scale(0.2) but we container scale object-render--canvas (from css) to scale(5), the result is perfect, we have the good quality image, in the same position. I was thinking something similar can be done to the canvas drawing. No solution for this?

Found the solution, it was quite simple. I simply read the css transform scale value (let's say 0.2), this means to get 1-1 we would need to scale 5 times. We add this scaling to the existing scaling you calculated , so we scale the matrix/canvas 8 times (instead of 3), then I get the quality i need. Thank you for the help
